# Can a query only use one index per table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
( SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE author_id = ? AND seen IS NULL )
UNION
( SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE author_id = ? AND date_time > ? )
```

Also I have these two indexes:

```
(author_id, seen)
(author_id, date_time)
```

---

I read somewhere:

> A query can generally only use one index per table when process the `WHERE` clause

As you see in my query, there is two separated `WHERE` clause. So I want to know, *"only one index per table"* means my query can use just one of those two indexes or it can use one of those indexes for each subquery and both indexes are useful?

In other word, is this sentence true?

*"always one of those index will be used, and the other one is useless"*

Comment: Why not run "explain" on the query and find out?

Comment: in different query  (select ..) you can force the use of different index ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Are subqueries different query?

Comment: In your case you are using union and these are two separated query .. united in a result query

Comment: I think the key word there is *generally*. In the most common cases it won't be advantageous not so much as it's completely unthinkable.

Comment: @Stack  .. anywaya i have posted the comment as answer with s link to mysql docs .. hope is useful

Comment: 'I read somewhere' is not a sufficient motivation for this question. Stack Overflow isn't a clearing-house for arbitrary Internet rubbish. You need to provide a citation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That statement about only using one index is no longer true about MySQL.  For instance, it implements the *index merge* optimization which can take advantage of two indexes for some `where` clauses that have `or`.  [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html) is a description in the documentation.

You should try this form of your query and see if it uses index mer:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE author_id = ? AND (seen IS NULL OR date_time > ? );
```

This should be more efficient than the `union` version, because it does not incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Also, depending on the distribution of your data, the above query with an index on `mytable(author_id, date_time, seen)` might work as well or better than your version.

Comment: But I think this index would be more better: `mytable(author_id, date_time, seen)`. Because you said me *(elsewhere)* when there is `>` then that column should be the last one in the index group.

Comment: @Stack . . . In this case, it doesn't make a difference because all the index entries for an author would need to be scanned (if you used only one index).

Comment: Ah I see. Just my last question. This query `. . . where col1 = ? and col3 = ?` would make any benefit of this index? `(col1, col2, col3)`

Comment: @Stack . . . Yes.  It will look up `col1` in the index and scan all the entries for that value, getting the row ids for the rows with matching `col3` values.

Answer (score 2):

`UNION` combines results of subqueries. Each subquery will be executed independent of others and then results will be merged. So, in this case `WHERE` limits are applied to each subquery and not to all united result.

In answer to your question: yes, each subquery can use some index.

Answer (score 1):

There are cases when the database engine can use more indexes for one select statement, however when filtering one set of rows really it not possible. If you want to use indexing on two columns then build one index on both columns instead of two indexes.

Comment: How exactly? *"build one index on both columns instead of two indexes"*

Comment: As you also wrote, index on (author_id, seen) instead of indexes (author_id) and ( seen), and for the other subquery (author_id, date_time) and not (author_id) (date_time).

Answer (score 1):

Every single subquery or part of composite query is itself a query can be evaluated as single query for performance and index access .. you can also force the use of different index for eahc query .. In your case you are using union and these are two separated query .. united in a resulting  query 
.  you can have a brief guide how mysql ue index .. acccessing at this guide

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html